# AzDo wiki review/lock to avoid accidental edits

Tags: wiki

In my project , I have a wiki which has user guides for build contributors in my org. I have given right to contributors to edit it but at the same time I do not want them to edit without my knowledge  (to avoid accidental edit) something like a review request. Apart from forcing this manually as a procedure what else can be done? Some wiki policy that I am unaware about? Some tricks?

Is it achievable?

Comment: For our edification, I hope you'll share what you ultimately decide to do.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is at odds with [Wiki's Open and Trust Principles](http://wiki.c2.com/?WikiDesignPrinciples). However, you could achieve it with Azure DevOps Wiki by visiting each page you want to watch and "[Following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/follow-notifications-wiki-pages?view=azure-devops)" the page. You would then receive notification of edits and could review them ([View Revisions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-view-history?view=azure-devops#view-wiki-page-revision-history)) and make any changes you deemed necessary.

For what it's worth, I find these open feature requests:

- [Follow Entire Wiki](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/6591)
- [Follow a tree in a wiki page](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/follow-a-tree-in-a-wiki-page/531349)

Comment: Hi ,Appreciate your help and time. I understand the principle. But we are trying to create is for other people , kind-of guides and we do not want the to get corrupted by accidental or unwanted edits. Is there a way to force pull request or review request for project wiki?

Comment: The standard DevOps Wiki does not support pull or review requests - at this time. However, with credit to [this MS DeveloperCommunity thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/pull-requests-for-wiki/365737#T-N1056355) , apparently you could facilitate pull requests by creating your own separate repository and then publishing that repository as a Wiki. With that "non-standard Wiki" (repository) you can then implement the "Git workflow".

Comment: Just for clarity "[Git workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows)."

Comment: I feel like I should add that Wiki might not be the right tool for this, i.e. don't sharpen your hammer when what you really need is an axe.

Comment: I agree @scottwelker , actually what I am looking for is to have PR functionality along with wiki editor (no md in repos and anything). I can achieve what I wanted above by enabling cross repos policy (which protect all default branch) , after this is enabled it will not allow check-in directly on wiki(default:wikiMaster). You will have to navigate to this hidden repos and make change in md (on different branch) raise pull request. But with all these I LOOSE WIKI EDITOR !!! THERE IS NO WAY to have wiki editor and PR both.

Comment: Agreed. What you are looking to do is contrary to Wiki principles. Not the right tool for the job. Best of luck.